# How can I share a fully loaded colab notebook? i.e. No need to run the cells after sharing

Tags: google-colaboratory

I shared a colab notebook with a technophobe colleague who doesn't know how to python. I hid all the code cells, and the only thing left was a set of `ipywidgets` sliders and a dataframe. All they had to do was play with the sliders:

[image]

However none of them worked. He couldn't move the sliders.

Does a colab notebook have to be run from scratch by whoever you share it with? I made sure that editing permissions were granted before sharing, which I thought would allow them to adjust the sliders.

Answer (score 0):

Just ask them to use a different computer/browser. It is most likely an issue with their browser not rendering your knobs properly.
Since your colleague is a technophobe there is nothing else we can advise given the info you provided.

Comment: OK, he used Chrome. The knobs were rendered but they couldn't be moved. Thought Chrome would be the best browser to use actually. So you're saying that all variables should be fully loaded already if a notebook is shared?

Comment: Yes, if you saved it properly on your end, the variables should be fully loaded in a shared notebook. However, Chrome is not always the best browser because often it blocks legitimate traffic (for me it recently blocked Amazon Prime movies). Their cookie/security settings often cause issues.

Comment: We tried something else. Rather than playing with the sliders, he tried to print a dataframe that should be loaded. `print(data.head())` and got the error: `'data' is not defined`. So it's not just a problem with the slider. None of the variables are loaded. What can I try next? Any ideas? I also saved before sharing.